# Windows7 machine cannot access Linux share folders via Samba, help please

Tags: networking, server, windows-7, samba, file-sharing

I have a linux and a windows 7 machine connected via samba. My linux machine is able to gain access to the folders on the windows 7 machine via the browse network tab in file manager but the windows 7 machine is not able to see the linux machine via windows explorer. I have a vast knowledge of windows but am relatively new to linux so i apologize if i seem noobish. I am able to ping the windows ip and vice versa. again i apologize for seeming noobish. i hope i am presenting the valid information, any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you

Solutions i have tried so far:

1. using the run dialogue box from windows to access using ip

   > \\ip-of-linux-machine
2. using the run dialogue box from windows to access using pc name

   > \\pc-name

here is a copy of my smb.conf settings

> [global]
>
> workgroup = WORKGROUP
>
> server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
>
> ;   wins server = w.x.y.z
>
> dns proxy = no
>
> ;   name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast
>
> ;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0
>
> ;   bind interfaces only = yes
>
> log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
>
> max log size = 1000
>
> syslog = 0
>
> panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
>
> encrypt passwords = true
>
> passdb backend = tdbsam
>
> obey pam restrictions = yes
>
> unix password sync = yes
>
> passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
>    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* >%n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
>
> pam password change = yes
>
> map to guest = bad user
>
> ;   domain logons = yes
>   ;   logon path = \%N\profiles\%U
>
> ;   logon drive = H:
>
> ;   logon script = logon.cmd
>
> ; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" >%u
>
> ; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u
>
> ; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g
>
> ;   printing = bsd
>   ;   printcap name = /etc/printcap
>
> ;   printing = cups
>   ;   printcap name = cups
>
> ;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m
>
> ;   message command = /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/linpopup "%f" "%m" %s; rm %s' &
>
> ;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
>   ;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
>   ;   template shell = /bin/bash
>
> ;   winbind enum groups = yes
>   ;   winbind enum users = yes
>
> ;   usershare max shares = 100
>
> usershare allow guests = yes
>
> ;[homes]
>   ;   comment = Home Directories
>   ;   browseable = no
>
> ;   read only = yes
>
> ;   create mask = 0700
>
> ;   directory mask = 0700
>
> ;   valid users = %S
>
> ;[netlogon]
>   ;   comment = Network Logon Service
>   ;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
>   ;   guest ok = yes
>   ;   read only = yes
>
> ;[profiles]
>   ;   comment = Users profiles
>   ;   path = /home/samba/profiles
>   ;   guest ok = no
>   ;   browseable = no
>   ;   create mask = 0600
>   ;   directory mask = 0700
>
> [printers]
>     comment = All Printers
>     browseable = no
>     path = /var/spool/samba
>     printable = yes
>     guest ok = no
>     read only = yes
>     create mask = 0700
>
> [print$]
>     comment = Printer Drivers
>     path = /var/lib/samba/printers
>     browseable = yes
>     read only = yes
>     guest ok = no
>   ;   write list = root, @lpadmin
>
> ;[cdrom]
>   ;   comment = Samba server's CD-ROM
>   ;   read only = yes
>   ;   locking = no
>   ;   path = /cdrom
>   ;   guest ok = yes
>
> ;   preexec = /bin/mount /cdrom
>   ;   postexec = /bin/umount /cdrom

Comment: Have you checked that anyone has the read and write permission for the folder you are trying to share in Ubuntu? Right click on the folder in Ubuntu and click on properties. Make sure everyone can read and write to the folder.

Comment: You can also try ticking the "guest access" box on the folder share permissions and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

After breaking my head for a long time, it was the firewall.
Try (you or whoever sees this ticket) to disable firewall and check if it is working:

`sudo ufw disable`

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any custom shares specified in your configuration file. But if you are new to the OS, I would suggest for you to install a graphical samba shares manager, this way, you can create your shares via GUI, and later inspect your `smb.conf` file to understand them.

To install the above mentioned GUI on Ubuntu:

1. Make sure your repositories are up to date:

   ```
   $sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install Samba GUI:

   ```
   $sudo apt-get install system-config-samba
   ```
3. Search for "samba" on your application launcher

After starting this application, it will be much easier to setup your shares and browse them from a Windows client, same method you where using before.